# How to delete data in multi dimension array by its key in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, key

Here is my data array and I want to delete by key `CSH4870543427`

```
var object = {};

 object ={
            0:{id:'CSH4870543427',actual_selling_price: "7.27"},
            1:{id:'CSH4002543427',actual_selling_price: "7.30"}
         };

var dataArray = [];
$.each(object,function(index, entry){
    dataArray[entry.id] = entry;
});
```

How Can I delete data using key ?

Here is my code

```
 var item = "CSH4870543427";
   var index = dataArray.indexOf(item);
   dataArray.splice(index, 1);
```

Above code not working

Comment: Are you sure that is an array? Please provide valid data.

Comment: Your code's syntax is not even valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. first your dataArray is not a valid array, you can't even run this code without getting an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
```

so first fix your dataArray, then you can use something like.

```js
dataArray.map((data) => delete data[key]);
```

**Update**

just use

```js
delete dataArray['CSH4870543427']
```

Comment: I Updated my question

Answer (score 0):

```
delete dataArray[CSH4870543427]
```

will delete the specified key from your object. if you were trying to say the dataArray is an object like this.

```
var dataArray =    {CSH4870543427: {actual_selling_price: "7.27"}, CSH4002543427: {actual_selling_price: "75.95"}, INV1355743427: {actual_selling_price: "5.95"}}
```